# Ajuda com jquery Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estou com um problema em um seletor de filtro, quando escolho uma cidade para filtrar informações sobre ela, o console do navegador me mostra o erro abaixo. Não sei dizer qual versão do Jquery está sendo usada no site, estou caindo de paraquedas no mundo do js rs.

Em localhost com o jquery 2 funcionou perfeitamente, depois que subi para o servidor, começou a dar esse erro e parou de funcionar o filtro.

Jquery utilizado no site: https://jsfiddle.net/gLep8kdn/

Código completo do custom js https://jsfiddle.net/0kLjj0y5/

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.filterList (custom.js:3)

Código

```
$('select[name="list_citys"]').change(filterList);   3 ª linha

function filterList(e) {
var value = e.target.value;
$(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").parent().parent().removeClass("hidden");
if (value == "all_city") $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideDown();
else {
    $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideUp();

    $(".list_citys_shop ul:not([data-category*=" + value + "])").parent().addClass("hidden");
    $(".list_citys_shop ul[data-category*=" + value + "]").find(".new-citys").stop().slideDown();
  }                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente o jQuery não foi carregado.

Comment: Está sendo carregado normalmente, pois as demais funções do site funcionam.

Comment: Tem como colocar todo o código JS? O que tem nas duas linhas anteriores à linha que dá o erro?

Comment: Apenas comentários do que o código executa. 

Depois desse código, vem o bootstrap js 

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Aqui o código completo 

https://jsfiddle.net/0kLjj0y5/

Comment: O código no jsfiddle dá o mesmo erro, pelo mesmo (provável) motivo pelo qual dá erro no seu site. Verifique o ponto no qual indica o caminho para o jQuery.

Comment: E onde está importando o jQuery?

Comment: Não @AndersonCarlosWoss o jquery está sendo chamado em outro arquivo antes do custom js



<script src="/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=/assets/custom.js"></script>




Não tem como chamar o jquery em outro lugar, pois está sendo utilizado aquelas plataformas de criação de site (Apenas estou prestando manutenção) e o suporte disse que não tem como mexer no template.

Comment: O código em produção http://loja.bluebeach.com.br/preview/testelojas2-126/v  ctrl + u e pesquise por jquery e custom.js

Comment: Leandro misturar Angular e jQuery pode ser um dos motivos, realmente não vejo necessidade de usar ambos, apesar de diferentes e sua maneira de trabalhar, pelo que olhei no código da pagina algo esta sobreescrevendo a variavel global `$`.

Comment: Pois é, Guilherme, o pior é que não tenho como editar nem remover arquivos, pois o site foi feito naquelas plataformas prontas e os caras mal deixam você mexer no js, eles analisam todo o código antes de publicar.

Comment: Tentei reproduzir o mínimo do seu código no JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ahp9cyn3/) e aparentemente está funcionando.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é algum script que esta sobrescrevendo o `$`, talvez o Angular.js

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWosso custom.js é chamado umas 10 linhas abaixo do jquery, como você disse, ele está funcionando normalmente no jsfiddle, pode ser um arquivo do angular sobrescrevendo o $ mesmo, vou fazer um teste igual o Guilherme sugeriu.

Comment: Pessoal, vou testar a dica do Guilherme, mas provavelmente só vou obter resposta do suporte (Alterar o custom js) lá por segunda a tarde, aí eu posto o resultado aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provavelmente é a ordem que adicionou o jQuery, a ordem no HTML deve ser sempre esta:

```
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery1.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery2.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery3.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
```

Se estiver usando bootstrap, então a ordem será esta:

```
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery1.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery2.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/plugin-jquery3.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
```

Se fizer algo como isto:

```
<script src="caminho do jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
```

Ou assim:

```
<script src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

Vai falhar, porque o bootstrap usa o jQuery mas na ordem do carregamento o jQuery ainda não foi solicitado.

Então lembre-se, o jQuery deve vir antes de tudo

**Note que** se você estiver usando o atributo `async` pode também ocasionar falhas, como por exemplo:

```
<script async src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js"></script>
```

Pois o custom.js não vai esperar o jquery.js carregar, outra coisa importante notar é se não esta carregando dois jQuery ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo:

```
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="caminho do jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Protegendo o escopo

Outra coisa que pode estar ocorrendo é que alguma biblioteca como o Angular.js (ou outra) pode estar sobrescrevendo a variável `$`:

- Uma maneira de resolver é trocar o `$` por `jQuery`
- Outra maneira é isolar o escopo, assim por exemplo:

  ```
  (function ($) {
      $(...).funcao(...);
  })(jQuery);
  ```

> **nota:** Realmente não vejo a necessidade de usar misturar angular.js com jQuery, mesmo que ambos sejam distintos, Angular é bem especifico, se for usar pra uma coisa simples como um botão apenas então melhor nem usar Angular.

Comment: Acredito que a ordem esteja correta, Guilherme, código em produção > http://loja.bluebeach.com.br/preview/testelojas2-126/v

Comment: @Leonardo Atualizei a resposta, de uma olhada no final que adicionei, isso deve ajudar a corrigir

Comment: vou testar as duas maneiras, mas provavelmente só vou obter resposta do suporte (Alterar o arquivo) lá por segunda a tarde, aí eu comento aqui se deu certo. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Leonardo vai por mim, o provável erro é misturar angular.js com jquery :/, mas pode esperar um retorno do suporte se desejar.

Comment: Não entendo muito de jquery e angular também acho que é o mais provável. Na verdade eu dependo do suporte, só eles podem atualizar o arquivo custom,js, isso é tenso rs, mais uma vez muito obrigado, assim que receber uma resposta deles, eu aviso se deu certo.

Comment: Recebi uma resposta do suporte, sua sugestão em trocar todos os $ por jQuery funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado @Guilherme.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você esteja trabalhando com Wordpress, como em meu caso, use esta solução:

```
;(function($){
    // seu código
})(jQuery);
```

Pego em [SOF em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26819916/3063226)